# Listview changes image on number of lines when i'm trying to update one line

Tags: android

I have a list of items, which i'd like to "check" with filled star when user clicks on one item in the list.

I have a ListView with text & image, represented in XML layout, and using simple StringAdapter.

I've implemented the above by doing this:

```
        this.listViewSub.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView parent, final View view, final int position,
                final long id) {

                    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.unchkImg);
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.starchk);
```

I guess its not the right way to do it, but i don't have any idea how else to code it.
This code for some reason changes few random items in the list, and after one click i have about 4-5 items with icon changed.

Any idea how to solve it correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, after long search - i've found the answer in an article:
http://www.codegod.biz/WebAppCodeGod/Android-ListView-with-dynamic-Images-AID588.aspx

That was a tough one.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without code, but my first guess is that as the views get recycled, if you don't reset the ImageView to use the default "unchecked" image in the getView method, each time you star an item the view will remain starred, even it is used for a different item. So your adapter should just reset the ImageView's image resource ; though in that case, you'll have to remember which items you starred in order to reset the ImageView correctly : set it to do the default drawable or to the starred one.